# How to tell Proguard to avoid obfuscating JNA library classes?

Tags: java, proguard, jna

In other words: what `-keep` commands should I use to tell Proguard to avoid obfuscating my classes that represent native libraries?  (since JNA requires that the names match the equivalent native function, struct, etc.)

Comment: Any class members which depend on explicit naming for JNA to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rule I'm using for now:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.sun.jna.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

I still think there might be a better way to do it though.

Comment: Better in what way? A shorter, more concise rule?  More accurate or correct?  I guess "more correct" is the only "better" that matters.

Comment: @technomage - My hunch is that I only really need to keep classes that extend certain classes from JNA (`Structure`, `Library`, etc.).  In theory, other classes extended from JNA classes might be safe to obfuscate.  So, better in the sense that less code would be kept unnecessarily.  I'd have to spend some time with the JNA documentation to figure it out, though, and for my application it shouldn't matter, so I don't plan to look into it further.

Comment: At the moment, I'm working on keeping public fields for subclasses of Structure and public methods for subclasses of Library.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me worked as well

```
-keep class com.sun.jna.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.sun.jna.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it using these rules instead, because it seems they need everything of the package to be de-obfuscated:

```
-keep class com.sun.jna.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.sun.jna.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

JNA by default uses Library interface method names to look up native function names.  Anything other than those should be able to withstand obfuscation.

If your tests include coverage of all JNA calls then you should be able to test this almost as fast as asking the question here.

**EDIT**

Consider this a comment, since I'm not prepared to offer "-keep" commands :)

You certainly must avoid elimination or reordering of any Structure fields.

Comment: My goal is to come up with a rule that is "future-proof" so the obfuscation will still work even if more JNA libraries are coded.  Actually I already have a solution, but to be fair, [I am giving others an opportunity to answer before I do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking),

Comment: "You certainly must avoid elimination or reordering of any Structure fields." - I hadn't considered that, thanks.